# Python's `urllib2`: Why do I get error 403 when I `urlopen` a Wikipedia page?

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I have a strange bug when trying to `urlopen` a certain page from Wikipedia. This is the page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCola_(drink)

This is the shell session:

```
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCola_(drink)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 4.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "c:\Python26\Lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\Python26\Lib\urllib2.py", line 397, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\Python26\Lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\Python26\Lib\urllib2.py", line 435, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\Python26\Lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Python26\Lib\urllib2.py", line 518, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

This happened to me on two different systems in different continents. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: You might want to URL-encode those parentheses. Not that it helps against the 403, though.

Comment: You could also use links from the wikimedia api https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Answer (score 139, accepted):

[Wikipedias stance is](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Bot_policy#Unacceptable_usage):

> Data retrieval: Bots may not be used
>   to retrieve bulk content for any use
>   not directly related to an approved
>   bot task. This includes dynamically
>   loading pages from another website,
>   which may result in the website being
>   blacklisted and permanently denied
>   access. If you would like to download
>   bulk content or mirror a project,
>   please do so by downloading or hosting
>   your own copy of our database.

That is why Python is blocked. You're supposed to [download data dumps](http://download.wikimedia.org/).

Anyways, you can read pages like this in Python 2:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
con = urllib2.urlopen( req )
print con.read()
```

Or in Python 3:

```
import urllib
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
con = urllib.request.urlopen( req )
print(con.read())
```

Comment: "That is why Python is blocked. " I don't get what is this sentence means?    

However, even I made a list of 'User-Agent' and randomly choose one of them to construct a url, the website will sent me "urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] >" or just blocked my ip from visiting their website.  

Can you give me more ideas?  

Many thanks.

Comment: It's totally ridiculous that they also block `HEAD` request which are useful e.g. to validate all links posted by a user.

Comment: This approach also works for me for a HTTPS page that is returning me a 403. Why does it work, whereas `urllib2.urlopen()` results in a 403?

Comment: Also, if you are getting error 403 when working with an api you should use the solution described above

Answer (score 11):

To debug this, you'll need to trap that exception.

```
try:
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCola_(drink)')
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.fp.read()
```

When I print the resulting message, it includes the following

> "English
>
> Our servers are currently experiencing
>   a technical problem. This is probably
>   temporary and should be fixed soon.
>   Please try again in a few minutes. "

Comment: File "<ipython-input-63-d436df366a51>", line 3
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @KHANirfan That's python2 syntax. Python3 exception syntax is "except Exception as e: print(e)".

Answer (score 5):

Often times websites will filter access by checking if they are being accessed by a recognised user agent.  Wikipedia is just treating your script as a bot and rejecting it.  Try spoofing as a browser.  The following link takes to you an article to show you how.

http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/changeua.php

Answer (score 1):

Some websites will block access from scripts to avoid 'unnecessary' usage of their servers by reading the headers urllib sends. I don't know and can't imagine why wikipedia does/would do this, but have you tried spoofing your headers?

Answer (score 1):

As Jochen Ritzel mentioned, Wikipedia blocks bots.

However, bots will not get blocked if they use the PHP api.
To get the Wikipedia page titled "love":

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=love&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround for this using php which is not blocked by the site I needed.

it can be accessed like this:

```
path='http://phillippowers.com/redirects/get.php? 
file=http://website_you_need_to_load.com'
req = urllib2.Request(path)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
vdata = response.read()
```

This will return the html code to you