# Python 3.4 urllib.request error (http 403)

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to open and parse a html page. In python 2.7.8 I have no problem:

```
import urllib
url = "https://ipdb.at/ip/66.196.116.112"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

and everything is fine. However I want to move to python 3.4 and there I get HTTP error 403 (Forbidden). My code:

```
import urllib.request
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url) # same URL as before

File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 461, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 574, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 499, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 582, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

It work for other URLs which don't use https.

```
url = 'http://www.stopforumspam.com/ipcheck/212.91.188.166'
```

is ok.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336549/pythons-urllib2-why-do-i-get-error-403-when-i-urlopen-a-wikipedia-page

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It seems like the site does not like the user agent of Python 3.x.

Specifying `User-Agent` will solve your problem:

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
```

**NOTE** Python 2.x urllib version also receives 403 status, but unlike Python 2.x urllib2 and Python 3.x urllib, it does not raise the exception.

You can confirm that by following code:

```
print(urllib.urlopen(url).getcode())  # => 403
```

Comment: @Matian2049, Need more information, could you post a separate question with more detail.

Comment: sorry, i made it working. it seems to have failed because of the VPN i was using.

Comment: Seems as if you can use that Mozilla user agent for Microsoft Edge as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some notes I gathered on `urllib` when I was studying python-3:
I kept them in case they might come in handy or help someone else out.

## How to import `urllib.request` and `urllib.parse`:

```
import urllib.request as urlRequest
import urllib.parse as urlParse
```

## How to make a GET request:

```
url = "http://www.example.net"
# open the url
x = urlRequest.urlopen(url)
# get the source code
sourceCode = x.read()
```

## How to make a POST request:

```
url = "https://www.example.com"
values = {"q": "python if"}
# encode values for the url
values = urlParse.urlencode(values)
# encode the values in UTF-8 format
values = values.encode("UTF-8")
# create the url
targetUrl = urlRequest.Request(url, values)
# open the url
x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)
# get the source code
sourceCode = x.read()
```

## How to make a POST request (`403 forbidden` responses):

```
url = "https://www.example.com"
values = {"q": "python urllib"}
# pretend to be a chrome 47 browser on a windows 10 machine
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}
# encode values for the url
values = urlParse.urlencode(values)
# encode the values in UTF-8 format
values = values.encode("UTF-8")
# create the url
targetUrl = urlRequest.Request(url = url, data = values, headers = headers)
# open the url
x  = urlRequest.urlopen(targetUrl)
# get the source code
sourceCode = x.read()
```

## How to make a GET request (`403 forbidden` responses):

```
url = "https://www.example.com"
# pretend to be a chrome 47 browser on a windows 10 machine
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}
req = urlRequest.Request(url, headers = headers)
# open the url
x = urlRequest.urlopen(req)
# get the source code
sourceCode = x.read()
```

Comment: I apologize for the errors in my old answer, I've done some research and fixed those. Those errors have inspired me to go back and check if my notes are all correct :D

Comment: Why it is working for second link without any issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The **urllib request HTTP 403 error** occurs due to a server security feature that blocks known bot `user-agents`.
Here are possible solutions in order of **feasibility** (easiest to apply first):-

### **Solution 1:-**

Add a different `user-agent` that's just NOT considered a bot.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 
web = "https://www.festo.com/de/de" 
headers = {
   "User-Agent": "XYZ/3.0",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
} 
request = Request(web, headers=headers) 
content = urlopen(request).read()
```

Optionally, you can set a short timeout for the request, if you're running **multiple requests** consecutively.

```
content = urlopen(request,timeout=10).read()
```

### **Solution 2:-**

Add a cookie from your browser after opening the url manually and accepting all cookies.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 
web = "https://www.festo.com/de/de" 
headers = {
   "User-Agent": "XYZ/3.0",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", 
   "cookie": "value stored in your webpage"
} 
request = Request(web, headers=headers) 
content = urlopen(request).read()
```

If you're using chrome, you can log onto the `web` url and open the **inspector** (press F12), then choose the **Application** tab, then from the left tree choose **Cookies** under **Storage**

### **Solution 3:-**

If obtaining the cookie needs to be done for several websites, it would be deemed wise to create the `request` using the `Session` object due to it's compatibility with cookies.

```
import requests
web = "https://www.festo.com/de/de" 
headers = {
   "User-Agent": "XYZ/3.0",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
} 
request = requests.Session()
content = request.get(web,headers=headers).text
```

### Extra:-

If **SSL certificate verification fails** while using `urllib`

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen 
import ssl
web = "https://www.festo.com/de/de" 
headers = {
   "User-Agent": "XYZ/3.0",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
} 
request = Request(web, headers=headers)

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE 

content = urlopen(request,context=ctx).read()
```

Credits to the following [`Question 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086383/python-requests-403-forbidden-despite-setting-user-agent-headers), [`Question 2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627227/problem-http-error-403-in-python-3-web-scraping), [`SSL-Certificate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337431/2224647)