# Python 3 urllib ignore SSL certificate verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a server setup for testing, with a self-signed certificate, and want to be able to test towards it.

**How do you ignore SSL verification in the Python 3 version of `urlopen`?**

All information I found regarding this is regarding `urllib2` or Python 2 in general.

`urllib` in python 3 has changed from `urllib2`:

**Python 2, urllib2**: `urllib2.urlopen(url[, data[, timeout[, cafile[, capath[, cadefault[, context]]]]])`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

**Python 3**: `urllib.request.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])`
https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.request.urlopen

So I know this can be done in Python 2 in the following way. However Python 3 `urlopen` is missing the context parameter.

```
import urllib2
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

urllib2.urlopen("https://your-test-server.local", context=ctx)
```

And yes I know this is a bad idea. This is only meant for testing on a private server.

I could not find how this is supposed to be done in the Python 3 documentation, or in any other question. Even the ones explicitly mentioning Python 3, still had a solution for urllib2/Python 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the ssl check in python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770129/how-do-i-disable-the-ssl-check-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The accepted answer just gave advise to use python 3.5+, instead of direct answer. It causes confusion.

For someone looking for a direct answer, here it is:

```
import ssl
import urllib.request

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

with urllib.request.urlopen(url_string, context=ctx) as f:
    f.read(300)
```

Alternatively, if you use `requests` library, it has much better API:

```
import requests

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    resp = requests.get(url_string, verify=False)
    f.write(resp.content)
```

The answer is copied from this post (thanks @[falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru)): [How do I disable the ssl check in python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770129/how-do-i-disable-the-ssl-check-in-python-3-x/33770290)

These two questions should be merged.

Comment: I came across this answer after setting `verify=False` (using `requests` library) and realized that I was now getting a lot of warnings from `urllib3` which made it hard to read some of my logs during development. If anyone has this issue, see [this part of the urllib3 documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings)

Answer (score 6):

Python 3.0 to 3.3 does not have context parameter, It was added in Python 3.4. So, you can update your Python version to [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.request.urlopen) to use context.

Comment: You can just change default context: `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context` and you don't need ctx at all.

Comment: Thanks @AstraSerg, I think your comment would deserve to be converted to a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `cert_reqs='CERT_NONE'` while creating `PoolManager` or `ProxyManager` objects.

For example:

```
proxy = urllib3.ProxyManager("https://localhost:8443", cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
```

or

```
pool = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
```