# python3-urllib3: disable SSL certificate checking

Tags: ssl-certificate, python-3.7, urllib3

How can I disable SSL certificate checking in `urllib3`?

My application uses `urllib.request.Request`:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

but this function no longer supports the [context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337431/7287412)
parameter.

My python version is `3.7.3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable SSL verification like this;

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
```

And then use `http` as you like;

```
http.request("GET", "www.example.com")
```

Comment: how do I add it to the existing code? It uses `urllib.request.Request` on line 1209: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQsKu1Ew

Comment: That is not `urllib3` :(