# Unable to view the page source of a website

Tags: python, urllib2, http-error

I wrote a simple python script just to view the page source of a website.The website is `https://kissanime.to`. I am using the following small piece of code.

```
    import urllib2
    url = 'https://kissanime.to'
    link = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    print link
```

However the above process is not working and is showing the error message as follows

`HTTP Error 403 : Forbidden`

i tried a finding a solution to the above problem in the community and came up with this :-

```
     import urllib2
     url = 'https://kissanime.to'
     link1 = urllib2.Request(url,headers = {'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
     link2 = urllib2.urlopen(link1)
```

However the above method also fails and now i am getting the error:-

`HTTP Error 503 : Service Temporarily Unavailable`

Is there any kind of workaround to this problem? I am all new to this web-crawling features of python.
please help.

Comment: My guess is the user agent is your problem - the site is blocking you.  This is probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396036/python-3-4-urllib-request-error-http-403

Comment: so what would be the solution to the problem?

Comment: It's in the link I provided.  You have to specify a user agent that the site accepts.

Comment: and that would be the version and the name of the browser i am using? i am using python 2.7.10 . sorry for asking very basic questions but it is all very new to me.

Comment: No problem, web scraping is a bit of art and a bit of science.  There's no one right user agent, but you can easily find out your own by just googling "find my browsers user agent", then make that the user agent for your program.  It's just a string that contains the information.

Comment: i tried providing the user agent yet it still shows `HTTP Error 503 : Service Temporarily Unavailable` i am using python 2.7.10 , is that the problem?

Comment: Looks like they're too clever in blocking automated access then.  You might have better luck with the `requests` library, or `mechanize`.  They have some more tools for identifying yourself as legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked out the website, it makes you wait for 5 seconds while it does something before displaying any of it's main content.

I used the `requests` module, to get at this initial page that says "Wait 5 seconds":

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://kissanime.to/")

# Throws an Insecure Platform warning on certain versions of python

print r.content
```

However, depending on what exactly you wish to scrape you can start by looking under the hood to comprehend how the site was built and devise a strategy for scraping the content you desire.

I must say having looked at the Network calls made in the site, it is pretty stubborn in that every call has tons of parameters and cookies embedded in them.

What specifically are you looking to scrape from this website?

*Also, the server is returning 503 when it shows the initial page that says "Wait 5 seconds..."*

Comment: Thanks it actually worked. BTW i am trying to download the episodes of one piece from that website . It felt really boring and time consuming trying to download them all by hand one after one.i have heard people using python to make lives easier so i also started learning stuff to make a web-crawler to download them

Comment: You might want to look at patterns in the video source urls, without having to go through the homepage. Just right-click on the video and you should see an option to see the video url. Can you post one of them here?

Comment: i did look them up and only thing that is different for all the url's is a signature substring. this is the download url for the video`https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=f28b2929ddeb2426&itag=18&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=texmex&ip=2001:19f0:6000:9ad4:5400:ff:fe20:66ec&ipbits=32&expire=1467135046&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=3149A7DDE3B2359A8FABFAC38E7CC4ED3E8FFBF7.DDB44E95904F82ACDA3A48DCCE3BECE59FC0224&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-a5m7zne6&ms=nxu&mt=1467120529&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAyLmxheDAyKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=38`