# Python requests - 403 forbidden - despite setting `User-Agent` headers

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.gamefaqs.com'
#headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}    
headers ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}


response = requests.get(url, headers)
```

`response.status_code`  is returning  403. 
I can browse the website using firefox/chrome, so It seems to be a coding error.

I can't figure out what mistake I'm making.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works if you make the request through a `Session` object.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://www.gamefaqs.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(response.status_code)
```

Output:

```
200
```

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is going on with the `Session` object that is making the difference? I've never had to make a `Session` object to scrape a site.

Comment: @Moondra The main thing about Session objects is its compatibility with cookies. For all you know, it's possible the site is setting and requesting cookies to be echoed back as a defence against scraping which is probably against its policy.

Comment: Cookies. I see. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried this for another website and it doesn't fix the issue, I still get a 403.

Comment: Same here, I'd like to learn if  you've found a solution? @SarahJessica

Comment: It was a while ago, I can't remember @talha06. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Using keyword argument works for me:

```
import requests
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.gamefaqs.com', headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try using a Session.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(response.status_code)
```

> If still the request returns 403 Forbidden (after session object &
> adding user-agent to headers), you may need to add more headers:

```
headers = {
    'user-agent':"Mozilla/5.0 ...",
    'accept': '"text/html,application...',
    'referer': 'https://...',
}
r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

In the chrome, Request headers can be found in the Network > Headers > Request-Headers of the Developer Tools. (Press F12 to toggle it.)

reason being, few websites look for user-agent or for presence of specific headers before accepting the request.