# Reading pdf remotely using urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, http-status-code-403, pypdf

I am trying to extract text from pdf remotely.

The url is this http://loc.gov/aba/publications/FreeLCC/A-text.pdf

My code is as follows

```
import urllib2
import PyPDF2
import io

URL = 'http://loc.gov/aba/publications/FreeLCC/A-outline.pdf'
remote_file = urllib2.urlopen(URL).read()
memory_file = io.BytesIO(remote_file)

read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(memory_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()

for i in range(0, number_of_pages):
    pageObj = read_pdf.getPage(i)
    page = pageObj.extractText()
    print (page)
```

I get a `403` HTTP error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336549/pythons-urllib2-why-do-i-get-error-403-when-i-urlopen-a-wikipedia-page)

```
import urllib2
import PyPDF2
import io

URL = 'http://loc.gov/aba/publications/FreeLCC/A-outline.pdf'
req = urllib2.Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 
remote_file = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
memory_file = io.BytesIO(remote_file)

read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(memory_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()

for i in range(0, number_of_pages):
    pageObj = read_pdf.getPage(i)
    page = pageObj.extractText()
    print (page)
```